# Obtain all combinations of 3 numbers with repetition.

Tags: matrices, vectors, combinations

I'm stuck with this problem and I'd like to get some help. I think there is something I'm not aware of. So, the thing is I'm given this control matrix H.

```
      0000111111111
H =   0111000111222
      1012012012012
```

I'm asked to obtain all the words of this code. The theory of linear and block codes says that a word V is that word which **H*Vt=0 (zero)** where Vt is transposed V.

Now the fun part is I have to implement it using **Pari GP**

At the moment I do know there are 3^10 = 59049 possible words. That is the size of the matrix which is obtained by powering the body q*in this case q=3* of the matrix to the dimension which is columns-rows.

**My problem is** I dont know how to generate all the vectors (words) so H*Vt = 0. That should be somethins like

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1] 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
.... 
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
...
[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

Am I correct in my thinking or there is soming I'm missing or misunderstanding? How could I generate all the vector V that I need.

At the moment I tried the **numtoperm()%3** function but that is not a good solution because there are being mixed 10 numbers converted to modulo 3 while I only need 0,1 and 2 to be mixed.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Is this a programming question?  If so, it might belong on a different exchange.

Comment: I'll ask it on s.overflow but I'm not so sure because I think I'm also failing at the maths part.

Comment: I tried answering at s.overflow, but the post got deleted.  The linear code is the nullspace of $H$.  One can find a basis for the nullspace by row reduction, but in this example, the matrix is already reduced: columns 1, 2, and 5 contain pivots.  So one can set the elements of the remaining 10 columns arbitrarily, and then compute the elements in positions 1, 2, and 5.  In Pari you can generate all possible vectors by looping through the integers 0 through $3^{10}-1$.  Use the command **digits** in base 3 to convert to a vector.  (You'll have to pad with zeros.)

Comment: If you need to carry out the process for a different $H$, and it isn't already row-reduced, you can use the Pari command **matsolvemod(H,3,0)** with flag=1 to obtain a set of basis vectors for the nullspace.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the length of your number is $n$.  Then, you're asking to generate all trinary numbers with at most $n$ digits.  Since there are three digits, there are $3^n$ such numbers.

To get the sequences you're looking for, you must look at the trinary numbers from $0$ to $3^n-1$.  For a general number $k$, you can construct the trinary representation in the following way:

The units digit is $k\pmod 3$, the three's digit is $\lfloor k/3\rfloor\pmod 3$, and, in general, the digit in the $l$'s position is $\lfloor k/3^{l-1}\rfloor\pmod{3}$.

Here's some pseudo-code that does a calculation, but in the reverse order.  It computes all ternary numbers with less than or equal to $n$ ternary places (but the final number is written in base 10 (just using 0, 1, and 2).

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 3^n; i++)
 {
      k=0;
      l=i;
      for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
      {
           k = k * 10 + (l % 3); // Compute the next digit mod 3
           l = (l - (l % 3))/3; // Subtract the units digit and divide by 3
      }
      print k;
 }
```

Note that this computes the integer $k$ in the *opposite order* as described in the original discussion.

Comment: This nice part about this method is that it generalizes nicely if you have more than $3$ digits.  If you only want something to work for 3 digits (not general use), then you can use the simpler nested for-loops (3 of them):
for i from 0 to n-1:
    for j from 0 to n-1:
        for k from 0 to n-1:
            output i, j, k

Comment: Thank you for the idea, now I have to think about the implementation of it in Pari GP syntax.

Comment: If you have a two dimensional array A, then: for m from 0 to 3^n-1{for l from 1 to n{A[m,l-1]=m%3^l}}

Comment: I tried to implement it as you said. In Pari it would be something like
`A=matrix(3^10,10);
for(i=1,3^10,
 for(j=1,10,
  A[i,j]=i%(3^j);
  print(A[i,j])
 );
);`

The for is pretty well idented but seems like in comments you can not format code.
The output I'm getting is pretty strange, here is a screenshot of it. http://i.gyazo.com/9a7170ca5ee5202b411ed0189648b881.png it loops 3^10 times

Comment: You're right!  I missed something, let me fix it:
for( i=1 , 3^10 , k=i ; for( j=1 , 10 , A[i,j]=k%3; k=k/3) ; );
Here, I'm assuming that $k/3$ truncates decimals.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the purpose of k=k/3 at the end of the loop??

Comment: For example, say you wanted the tens digit of $154$.  It would be the same as the ones digit of $\lfloor 154/10\rfloor$ since $154/10=15.4$, then rounding down gives $15$, whose units digit is $5$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24755/discussion-between-rzvgg-and-michael-burr).

Comment: Sorry, I can't chat now.

Comment: Don't worry :D Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I added pseudo code to the answer that should work well and not be too confusing, I hope.